# Guidelines for documenting your contributions to the Ubuntu project

Tags: community, contributing, ubuntu-membership

I'm looking for some guidance on how to keep track of the contributions I make to the project so I can present them as evidence when I eventually apply for [Ubuntu membership](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership). When I was listening to [Jono Bacon's weekly Q&A on Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/at-home-with-jono-bacon) earlier tonight, a question was asked about what was meant by a 'sizeable and sustained contribution' to the project, with respect to an Ubuntu membership application, he said that it consisted of a prolonged period of regular contributions which were logged in a wiki. Is this the Ubuntu wiki, or is that just reserved for high level projects? Also some advice on what's worth recording (every single bug report?) would also help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are supposed to create an Ubuntu Wiki page about yourself.

To do this, go to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YourName (replacing `YourName` with your actual name) and click on `Create a new empty page`.

As for what information to put on your wiki, I would look at what existing Ubuntu Members have on their wiki pages.

There is a list of Ubuntu Members at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntumembers/+members#active. Click on some profiles and see their respective wiki pages.